# iOS : invalid bit code version

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

I am using Xcode 7.3 with swift 2.1. I have integrated `Alamofire` in my project using cocoapod.

When I try to build my project, I am getting these errors:

> error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.42.1_0' Reader:
>   '703.0.29_0')
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

After a lot of researching, I found one solution from somewhere. That is to disable bitcode from main project "Build Settings".

I have tried it too, but still there is no hope.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Use lower version of `Alamofire` in cocoapod.

Comment: I agree with @pkc456 ...someone had this error in this post. take a look. hopefully it will help: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52070 One of the solutions was using a lower version of your pod.

Comment: Could you display what podfile looks like?

Comment: I just solved this error by adding some build configuration code in podfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/3.2.0 for your version of Xcode and Swift as:

```
pod 'Alamofire', ‘3.2.0'
```